# How to pass url as a parameter in Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a third party game on my page. The game accepts a .js file with the settings hosted on my server.
I am trying to pass it like this:

```
Rails.public_path + '/settings.js'
```

I expect the result to be:

```
 www.gameproviderspage.com?settings=www.mypage.com/public/settings.js
```

But I am getting:

```
 www.gameproviderspage.com?settings=www.gameproviderspage.com/public/settings.js
```

Comment: What is the value of `Rails.public_path` in rails console?

Comment: Can you provide the context of that line of code. Which file are you calling it in?

Comment: Rails.public_path value is  "/app/public"

Comment: public_path in rails gives public folder path of Current project. Could you please specify where are you doing it? Refer:- https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/Rails.public_path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
request.original_url + '/settings.js'
```

Comment: It returns "undefined local variable or method `request'". I am passing params in controller.